# Getting only first few characters when getting input value using Ionic 4 Keypress event with a scanner

Tags: ipad, keypress, ionic4, scanning

I'm implementing a ionic 4 based iOS app specifically designed for iPad. The app sends barcode data to server, scanned using a wireless scanner connected thru bluetooth to the app. TO enable autosave, I have written a **keypress** event capture method, which detects "enter" key press on scanner. When it detects "enter key" the data is automatically send to backend server.

Here is my html

```
<ion-item>
          <ion-label position = "floating" class="lab-font">Order/Tracking/UCC No.<ion-note style="color: red">*</ion-note></ion-label>
          <ion-input #order type = "text" text-uppercase formControlName = "order" (ionFocus) = "enableKey()" (ionBlur) = "scanOrder($event)" 
              (ionInput) = "checkRepeat()" (keypress)="handleKeyboardEvent($event)" class="lab-font" required ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
```

The keypress is triggered using (keypress)="handleKeyboardEvent($event)"

On the Typescript file, I have

```
 handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(event.key.toLowerCase() === "enter"){
      this.submitOrderSearch(this.order.value);
    }
  }
```

When we manually type using virtual keyboard, this works perfectly. But when we use a scanner (Wireless, bluetooth connected to iPAD, used as an input device) and scan a barcode last few characters are missed while we call submitOrderSearch method.

Will there be a delay in binding the value to the input field? Because the scanners reads the data pretty quickly and I can see the method detects enter key as soon as the scanner beeps. Or Am I missing something here?

Below is the bar code I'm using.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, we have worked around this issue with Timeout. I'm not sure whether this is the right approach, but for now, nothing else works with reliability.

In the type script I have changed this to

```
  //Method to handle enter event
  handleScanner(evt){
    setTimeout(() => {
      let value = evt.target.value;
      this.enterEvt = true;
      this.submitOrderSearch(value);
    },800);
  }
```

and in the HTML

```
<ion-input #order type = "text" text-uppercase formControlName = "order" 
              (ionInput) = "enableSerialNumbers($event)"  class="lab-font" (keyup.enter)="handleScanner($event)" required ></ion-input>
```

Basically the binding is happening little slower than the event itself. So a slight delay make sure that the value is properly bound to the control. The other way is to buffer key key which is pressed, and use the buffer to convert to string when enter key is pressed.